# Website Login Process

Tags: login, website, cookies

I have a subscription to a data service. It costs about $30 a year, really cheap service. My account expired  last week but I noticed I was still able to access the site as a subscribed user.

When I try to login from a computer, one which I have never accessed the site before, my username/password is rejected and I am told that my account has expired.

However, if I login from my home computer, which I have used many times to access my account from, I am logged in automatically. I have the “Save Password” feature on my Chrome browser and Firefox. So when I log on to the site, my account is automatically signed-in. What do you think is causing this glitch?

Is it that Firefox/Chrome have the auto login feature? Is it because of saved cookies? A saved certificate that is allowing me to login to the site even after my account has expired?

Answer (score 1):

It's your cookies. The saved passwords in your browser don't do anything different than you're doing manually when you log in from a different machine.

Comment: Well than why am I being logged in through the cookies method but not the basic input "Username/Password" method?? When I manually log in, I am rejected. When I log in through the browser with my saved credntials it logs me in automatically and I am not rejected.

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that you didn't see the login screen ("I am logged in automatically") when accessing from home. If you see the login page and it's just automatically populated but you're still clicking to submit, I'm not sure what's going on, but I'd guess a login bug that's still cookie-related. The website doesn't know if you have your browser set to remember your password, but it does know if you have an existing authentication cookie. You could confirm this by clearing cookies on your home machine - the saved passwords will still be there.